# More user friendly form

Tags: javascript, forms

SO I have this register form where I check things with javascript. I let it color change when it has an correct input. And if all netrys are correct I will let the submit button become visible. But the problem is when I am at my last textbox you have to click another one just to let the code run so I put an extra checkbox in it so that the user must check this and it will validate that it's OK and show the submit button. But if I add this checkbox the whole script just isn't working anymore.

```
<script>
        function start(){
            var element=document.getElementById("name");
            element.style.background="yellow";
            element=document.getElementById("pass1");
            element.style.background="yellow";
            element=document.getElementById("pass2");
            element.style.background="yellow";
            element=document.getElementById("email");
            element.style.background="yellow";
            document.getElementById('button').style.visibility='hidden';
        }
        function check(obj,form){
            var check=0;
            var data1=form.pass1.value;
            var data2=form.pass2.value;
            var element=document.getElementById("pass1");
            var element2=document.getElementById("pass2");
            if(data1==data2 && data1!=null && data2!=null && data1!='' && data2!=''){
                element.style.background="green";
                element2.style.background="green";
                check++;
            }
            element=document.getElementById("name");
            data1=form.name.value;
            if(data1==null || data1==''){
                element.style.background="yellow";
            }
            else{
                element.style.background="green";
                check++;
            }
            element=document.getElementById("email");
            data1=form.email.value;
            var atpos=data1.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=data1.lastIndexOf(".");
            if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=data1.length){
                element.style.background="yellow";
            }else{
                element.style.background="green";
                check++;
            }
            if(check==3){
                document.getElementById('button').style.visibility='visible';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('check').checked=false;
            }
            obj.style.background="yellow";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start();">
    <div id="register">
    <form name="login" action="logon.php" method="post">
        Username:<input id="name" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" name="username" type="text" size="14"/><br>
        Password:<input id="pass1" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" name="password1" type="password" size="14"/><br>
        Repeat Password:<input id="pass2" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" name="password2" type="password" size="14"/><br>
        Email:<input id="email" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" name="email" type="text" size="14"/><br>
        Validate<input id="check" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" type="checkbox"/><br>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The focus event fires only when you enter the field. Have you tried `change` or `keyup` events? `keyup` might take a bit more processing power but looking at your code it should not be a problem. `change` fires when you leave the field and change has occured.

Comment: I hope you have a very good reason for not using CSS and jQuery.

Comment: onchange and keyup doesn't do anything

Comment: @stevedc: Put the code in jsfiddle.net. It is easy to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id of your checkbox to something else .Then it will work Ex :-

```
<input id="checkbox" onfocus="check(this,this.form)" type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: If I changed onfocus to onchange the code does what it has to do